# Ansible notify: sudo sysctl -p --system

Tags: ansible

I have a requirement to update `/etc/sysct.conf`, but then I need to run `systemctl -p --system` if that is changed.

How can I achieve that in my playbook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this either by using a handler or registering the task and execute the reload task conditionally. The below snippet shows how to do this by registering file change

```
- copy:
    src: sysctl.conf
    dest: /etc/sysctl.conf
    owner: root
    group: root
  register: result

- shell: sysctl -p --system
  become: yes
  when: result.changed
```